# Having trouble with arguments and classes in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble with getting classes to work and passing arguments for those classes. i have figured out most of the other Errors i had on my own, but there is one error that is really bugging me. the error i am getting is for "objAttendee". the error says "Argument not specified for parameter "strFirstName" of public Sub New(ByVal strFirstName As String, ByVal strLastName As String, ByVal strCourses As String, ByVal intDays As String)". i am not at all sure how to fix this problem.

can anyone help me out with this?

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Attendee
    Dim objAttendee As New Attendee

    'class variables
    Private _strFirstName As String
    Private _strLastName As String
    Private _strCourses As String
    Private _intDays As Integer
    Private _decTotal As Decimal
    Private _decCostPerDay As Decimal = 350D
    Private _decPreConferenceCost As Decimal = 675D

    Sub New(ByVal strFirstName As String, ByVal strLastName As String, ByVal strCourses As String, ByVal intDays As String)
        'Contructor


        _strFirstName = strFirstName
        _strLastName = strLastName
        _strCourses = strCourses
        _intDays = Convert.ToInt32(intDays)

    End Sub

    Function ComputeCourseCosts() As Decimal

        'Calculates the cost if a pre-conference course is not selected
        _decTotal = _intDays * _decCostPerDay

        Return _decTotal
    End Function

    Function ComputePreConferenceCosts() As Decimal

        'Calculates the cost if a pre-conference course is selected
        _decTotal = _intDays * _decCostPerDay + _decPreConferenceCost

        Return _decTotal
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Argument not specified for parameter ".....*

**Plutonix** told you the origin of the issue :

You're declaring a Attendee object within your Attendee Class (which doesn't really makes sense)

```
Public Class Attendee
    Dim objAttendee As New Attendee ' <- offending code :P
```

But the constructor of that class is declared as follows :

```
    Sub New(ByVal strFirstName As String, ByVal strLastName As String, ByVal strCourses As String, ByVal intDays As String)
```

And you don't have a constructor without any parameter like :

```
    Public Sub New() ' No parameter required
        ' ...
    End Sub
```

And you don't have to create/declare such variant of Attendee constructor, otherwise, **you must have to define default values** for `_strFirstName`, `_strLastName`, `_strCourses` and `_intDays` !

I *think* that... you were in the urge to test your Attendee class, and declared an Attendee variable ***inside*** it ;) .

No, you *should* declare `Dim objAttendee As New Attendee(...)` outside your class (in the main block of your program for example) **with the appropriate parameters**.

```
    Private Sub ShowMyClass(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objAttendee As New Attendee("Simpson", "Homer", "Courses", "48")

        MessageBox.Show(objAttendee.ComputeCourseCosts().ToString())
    End Sub
```